# Use Spark to write Parquet files, how to enable dictionary for individual columns

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

When using Apache Spark to write Parquet files, there is a configuration that can be used to enable dictionary in Parquet:

```java
sparkSession.sqlContext.setConf(“parquet.enabled.dictionary”, “true”)
```

This enables all columns in the data set to be written out with dictionary encoding. Is there a way to control the dictionary encoding for individual columns when writing out Parquet files? That is, enable dictionary encoding for some columns but not for other columns, giving finer grain control over the use of dictionary encoding.

This is because for some numeric columns (like fields that stores amounts or quantities) dictionary encoding doesn’t bring any benefits, but for other columns dictionary encoding can be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to set a dictionary for a single column. The setting is as follows:

```
spark.conf.set("parquet.enable.dictionary#columnName", "true")
```

But the dictionary is enabled for all columns by default, so you can set all columns first Close the dictionary.

```
spark.conf.set("parquet.enable.dictionary", "false")
```

Comment: You can see this in the docs here: https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-hadoop/README.md